# Use java.util.Date with Slick 3.1.0-M1

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am new to Slick. I am using mysql and I am trying to retrieve some datetime from the database. Here are my imports

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import scala.slick.driver._
import java.util.Date
```

and here the line of the class where the mapping is

```
def creationDate = column[Date]("creation_date")
```

But I am getting this error

> could not find implicit value for parameter tt: slick.ast.TypedType[java.util.Date]

Is there a way to import a datetime from mysql to a java.util.Date without using String?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you can't use **`java.util.Date`** in the Column is 
 it's not supported in Slick, see the [documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html) in Table Rows part.

> The following primitive types are supported out of the box for JDBC-based databases in JdbcProfile (with certain limitations imposed by the individual database drivers):
>   **Date types: java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.Timestamp**

Thus, no implicit TypedType[C] is provided.

```
 def column[C](n: String, options: ColumnOption[C]*)
   (implicit tt: TypedType[C]): Rep[C] = {
```

If you try to find the children of TypedType,  you will find three time-relevant class in **`slick.driver.JdbcTypesComponent`**.

```
DateJdbcType for java.sql.Date
TimestampJdbcType for java.sql.Timestamp
TimeJdbcType for java.sql.Time
```

Also, **the types defined are in line with what is stated in the documentation, three time-relevant type**.

I use **`Timestamp`** with **Slick 3.0** in my program as following:

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Temp(creation_date: Timestamp)

class Tests(tag: Tag) extends Table[Temp](tag, "tests") {
  def creationDate = column[Timestamp]("creation_date")

  def * = creationDate <> ((creationDate: Timestamp) =>   
     Temp.apply(creationDate), Temp.unapply _)
}
```

In that way, you just have to convert Timestamp to any time-relevant type you want back and forth, but that should be no big deal.

Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @AllenChou excellent explanation, I changed and used java.sql.Date

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) ?

If not, you should give it a serious thought. And there is a slick-mapper project for it https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import com.github.tototoshi.slick.MySQLJodaSupport._

// then it works just the same
def creationDate = column[DateTime]("creation_date")
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use java.util.Date as is,
create mapping Date type to Timestamp.

```
import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import java.util.Date
import java.sql.Timestamp

implicit def mapDate = MappedColumnType.base[Date, Timestamp](
  d => new Timestamp(d.getTime),
  identity
)
```